# Как спозиционировать облако и его текст

Tags: html, css, svg

Подскажите, как правильно задать позиционирование и остальные настройки, чтобы было как на изображении?

```css
.container {
  width: 1230px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  background-image: url(../img/home.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper__sky {
  margin-top: 28px;
}

.wrapper__sky__txt {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper__sky__txt p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #2f1059;
}

.wrapper__sky__txt span {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #2f1059;
}
```

```html
<section id="sky" class="clearfix">
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper__sky">
      <img src="img/sky.png" alt="">
      <div class="wrapper__sky__txt">
        <p>Дом готов<span>, идёт внутренняя отделка. Срок сдачи: </span>Февраль 2016</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавь изображение которые есть.

Comment: Полностью фото макета?

Comment: картинку облака. Вообщем сделай div помести в него текст сделай нужной ширины и задай ему фон облака с размером фона - cover

Comment: У меня немного вышло, но вид у кода ужасный, может есть вариант сделать это правильнее?

Comment: добавьте результат сюда

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/leval11/nmbvf0q9/

Comment: Можно абсолютные пути на изображения в css на jsfiddle?

Comment: Хорошо, сделал.

Comment: Все равно не отображается

Comment: @Matc А вы не могли бы дать сылки на изображение дома и облако по отдельности. Я сразу бы вам предметно максимально близко сделал ответ. А то придется искать свои картинки, а вам потом придется подстраивать под себя.

Answer (score 5):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Облака сделал в формате svg, добавил к ним радиальный градиент.
  Текст тоже находится внутри файла SVG.
- Осталось добавить картинку внутрь файла svg и тогда всё будет вместе
  в одной системе координат и не будет разъезжаться друг относительно
  друга при изменении масштаба.

Добавление картинки внутрь svg файла:

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="80%" viewBox="0 0 600 400" id="svg2" version="1.1" >  

<image xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWkGU.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/>  
</svg>
```

- Поверх картинки накладываются облака с градиентом.

Добавляется текст, при этом всегда есть возможность позиционировать текст, менять цвет и величину букв.

```
<text xml:space="preserve" x="53" y="120" id="text4150" style="font-size:20px; font-weight:700; line-height:125%;">
    <tspan id="tspan4152" x="35" y="120">
      ВАША КВАРТИРА В НОВОСТРОЕ ЖДЁТ ВАС
    </tspan>
  </text>
```

*Ниже полный код банера:*

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 400" id="svg2" version="1.1" >
   <defs> 
        <radialGradient id="grad_N" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="#CFCFFF" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#D5D5D5" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#CBCBCB" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#BBBBFF" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>
  
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWkGU.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/>
<g fill-opacity="0.7">
  <path d="M80.013495 58.437011C89.239767 34.19332 132.98945 45.254557 160.027 42.090172c36.19294-4.235902 72.92456-6.122954 109.26574-3.441441 24.12331 1.779991 47.25497 11.62393 71.40989 12.905403 27.56585 1.462431 55.02641-7.440838 82.59457-6.022526 18.03461 0.927835 38.27924-0.49651 53.34234 9.463966 6.56868 4.343543 10.33632 12.344244 12.9054 19.788288 8.64005 25.034958 20.31017 56.325368 6.88288 79.153138-6.0529 10.29057-21.08894 11.82199-32.69369 14.62612-15.63316 3.77754-32.15405 1.22851-48.18016 2.58108-14.95868 1.26248-29.78781 3.81099-44.73874 5.16217-48.08735 4.34588-106.971 29.93711-144.5405 9.46395-33.29471-18.14365-92.19506 1.36487-137.657632-7.74324C62.733044 172.84139 55.32824 169.96153 61.085573 140.17124 78.538944 49.861879 74.256828 73.563691 80.013495 58.437011Z" id="path4138" style="stroke:none" fill="url(#grad_N)"/>
  
  <path id="path4140" d="m96.617096 80.828897c10.006704-7.178295 20.801454 8.848743 34.454664 2.252833 20.73955-10.019343 40.39843-15.528506 51.58136-0.53211 8.679 11.638612 21.08242 4.746416 30.75892 2.76745 10.74804-2.198109 18.93618-0.345558 32.03869-3.102876 15.99987-3.367045 36.33887 3.613988 49.04921 2.916507 23.96167-1.3149 43.56152-3.508802 65.38737-3.44144 24.41889 0.07537 48.71663 3.806416 73.13061 4.301795 15.77263 0.32004 31.548-1.218209 47.31982-0.860355 15.80111 0.358518 45.13272-8.861696 47.3198 3.011266 0 0 10.89363 38.356323-0.86035 50.331073-11.25721 11.46864-32.11067 1.87981-48.18018 1.72072-15.5096-0.15355-30.96483-3.27982-46.45944-2.58109-21.71705 0.97934-42.84551 7.88245-64.52702 9.46397-38.32759 2.79574-76.87363 1.06625-115.28826 0-46.51318-1.29104-92.87391-6.16863-139.37835-7.74324-23.50479-0.79586-54.810099 25.07954-70.549534-0.86036-8.725343-14.38009-10.670614-35.74355 8.127632-43.245063 14.526608-5.7969 35.953917-7.138691 46.075058-14.39908z" style="stroke:none" fill="url(#grad_N)"/>
  <g  style="font-family:sans-serif;fill:#321759"> 
  <text xml:space="preserve" x="53" y="120" id="text4150" style="font-size:20px; font-weight:700; line-height:125%;">
    <tspan id="tspan4152" x="35" y="120">
      ВАША КВАРТИРА В НОВОСТРОЕ ЖДЁТ ВАС
    </tspan>
  </text>
  <text xml:space="preserve" x="81.734215" y="66.18026" id="text4154" style="font-size:12.5px;line-height:125%;">
    <tspan  x="70" y="66.18026">
      Дом готов идёт внутренняя отделка
    </tspan>
  </text>
  <text  x="304" y="72"  transform="scale(1.0808186,0.92522464)" style="font-size:12.5px;line-height:125%;">
    <tspan  x="290" y="72">
      Срок сдачи:
    </tspan>
  </text>
  <text xml:space="preserve" x="355" y="67"  style="font-size:12.5px;line-height:125%;">
          Февраль 2018
      </text>  
   
    <text  x="100" y="165" id="text4162" style="font-size:12.5px;line-height:125%;">
          Уютная квартира в центре города и в 5 минутах от р. Волга
      </text> 
 </g>  
   </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Пример с анимацией

Допустим нужно анимировать облака вместе с рекламным текстом. 
Нужно, чтобы объекты появлялись из верхнего левого угла, двигались к центру и увеличивались по пути, занимая позицию фокуса (позиция на экране, где чаще всего фокусируется взгляд).

Для этого лучше всего подойдёт команда smil `transform="scale(n)"`

Реализация  команды анимации scale(n):

```
<animateTransform fill="freeze" attributeName="transform" type="scale" begin="0s" dur="8s"   
    values="1;2;2;2;1;1;1" repeatCount="3" />,
```

где -      `values="1;2;2;2;1;1;1"`  набор коэффициентов увеличения.

Паузы между увеличением и уменьшением достигаются повторением одинаковых цифр

`repeatCount="3"` - количество повторений полных циклов анимации

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1200 800" id="svg2" version="1.1" >
   <defs> 
        <radialGradient id="grad_N" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="#CFCFFF" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#D5D5D5" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#CBCBCB" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#BBBBFF" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>
  
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWkGU.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/>
  <g id="anBanner" transform="scale(1)"  fill-opacity="0.8">
  <path d="M80.013495 58.437011C89.239767 34.19332 132.98945 45.254557 160.027 42.090172c36.19294-4.235902 72.92456-6.122954 109.26574-3.441441 24.12331 1.779991 47.25497 11.62393 71.40989 12.905403 27.56585 1.462431 55.02641-7.440838 82.59457-6.022526 18.03461 0.927835 38.27924-0.49651 53.34234 9.463966 6.56868 4.343543 10.33632 12.344244 12.9054 19.788288 8.64005 25.034958 20.31017 56.325368 6.88288 79.153138-6.0529 10.29057-21.08894 11.82199-32.69369 14.62612-15.63316 3.77754-32.15405 1.22851-48.18016 2.58108-14.95868 1.26248-29.78781 3.81099-44.73874 5.16217-48.08735 4.34588-106.971 29.93711-144.5405 9.46395-33.29471-18.14365-92.19506 1.36487-137.657632-7.74324C62.733044 172.84139 55.32824 169.96153 61.085573 140.17124 78.538944 49.861879 74.256828 73.563691 80.013495 58.437011Z" id="path4138" style="stroke:none" fill="url(#grad_N)"/>
  
  <path id="path4140" d="m96.617096 80.828897c10.006704-7.178295 20.801454 8.848743 34.454664 2.252833 20.73955-10.019343 40.39843-15.528506 51.58136-0.53211 8.679 11.638612 21.08242 4.746416 30.75892 2.76745 10.74804-2.198109 18.93618-0.345558 32.03869-3.102876 15.99987-3.367045 36.33887 3.613988 49.04921 2.916507 23.96167-1.3149 43.56152-3.508802 65.38737-3.44144 24.41889 0.07537 48.71663 3.806416 73.13061 4.301795 15.77263 0.32004 31.548-1.218209 47.31982-0.860355 15.80111 0.358518 45.13272-8.861696 47.3198 3.011266 0 0 10.89363 38.356323-0.86035 50.331073-11.25721 11.46864-32.11067 1.87981-48.18018 1.72072-15.5096-0.15355-30.96483-3.27982-46.45944-2.58109-21.71705 0.97934-42.84551 7.88245-64.52702 9.46397-38.32759 2.79574-76.87363 1.06625-115.28826 0-46.51318-1.29104-92.87391-6.16863-139.37835-7.74324-23.50479-0.79586-54.810099 25.07954-70.549534-0.86036-8.725343-14.38009-10.670614-35.74355 8.127632-43.245063 14.526608-5.7969 35.953917-7.138691 46.075058-14.39908z" style="stroke:none" fill="url(#grad_N)"/>
  <g  style="font-family:sans-serif;fill:#321759"> 
  <text xml:space="preserve" x="53" y="120" id="text4150" style="font-size:20px; font-weight:700; line-height:125%;">
    <tspan id="tspan4152" x="35" y="120">
      ВАША КВАРТИРА В НОВОСТРОЕ ЖДЁТ ВАС
    </tspan>
  </text>
  <text xml:space="preserve" x="81.734215" y="66.18026" id="text4154" style="font-size:12.5px;line-height:125%;">
    <tspan  x="70" y="66.18026">
      Дом готов идёт внутренняя отделка
    </tspan>
  </text>
  <text  x="304" y="72"  transform="scale(1.0808186,0.92522464)" style="font-size:12.5px;line-height:125%;">
    <tspan  x="290" y="72">
      Срок сдачи:
    </tspan>
  </text>
  <text xml:space="preserve" x="355" y="67"  style="font-size:12.5px;line-height:125%;">
          Февраль 2018
      </text>  
   
    <text  x="100" y="165" id="text4162" style="font-size:12.5px;line-height:125%;">
          Уютная квартира в центре города и в 5 минутах от р. Волга
      </text> 
 </g>   
 <animateTransform fill="freeze" attributeName="transform" type="scale" begin="0s" dur="8s"   
 values="1;2;2;2;1;1;1" repeatCount="3" />
</g> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать с помощью позиционирования:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWkGU.jpg") no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 50px;
}

.item:first-child {
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/mfFr87/11310145.png")50% 50% no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  top: 40px;
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/gozjT7/11310145.png")50% 35% no-repeat;
}

.item:last-child {
  top: 80px;
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/mfFr87/11310145.png")50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <h3>LOREM</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Lorem Ispum Dolor</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>IPSUM</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```